# Hadoop Container failed even 100 percent completed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, timeout, hadoop2, nutch

I have setup a small cluster Hadoop 2.7, Hbase 0.98 and Nutch 2.3.1. I have wrote a custom job that simple first combine docs of same domain, after that each URL of domain (from cache i.e., a list) is first obtained from from cache and then corresponding key is used to fetched the object via `datastore.get(url_key)` and then after updating score, it is written via `context.write`.

The job should complete after all docs are processed but what I have observed that each attempt if failed due to timeout and progress is 100 percent complete show. Here is the LOG

```
attempt_1549963404554_0110_r_000001_1   100.00  FAILED  reduce > reduce node2:8042  logs    Thu Feb 21 20:50:43 +0500 2019  Fri Feb 22 02:11:44 +0500 2019  5hrs, 21mins, 0sec  AttemptID:attempt_1549963404554_0110_r_000001_1 Timed out after 1800 secs Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on request. Exit code is 143 Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
attempt_1549963404554_0110_r_000001_3   100.00  FAILED  reduce > reduce node1:8042  logs    Fri Feb 22 04:39:08 +0500 2019  Fri Feb 22 07:25:44 +0500 2019  2hrs, 46mins, 35sec AttemptID:attempt_1549963404554_0110_r_000001_3 Timed out after 1800 secs Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on request. Exit code is 143 Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
attempt_1549963404554_0110_r_000002_0   100.00  FAILED  reduce > reduce node3:8042  logs    Thu Feb 21 12:38:45 +0500 2019  Thu Feb 21 22:50:13 +0500 2019  10hrs, 11mins, 28sec    AttemptID:attempt_1549963404554_0110_r_000002_0 Timed out after 1800 secs Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on request. Exit code is 143 Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

What it is so i.e., when an attempt is 100.00 percent complete then it should be marked as successfull. Unfortunately, there is any error information other than timeout for my case. How to debug this problem ?
My reducer is somewhat posted to another question
[Apache Nutch 2.3.1 map-reduce timeout occurred while updating the score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778616/apache-nutch-2-3-1-map-reduce-timeout-occurred-while-updating-the-score)

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that, in the mentioned 3 logs the time required for execution is varied with big difference. Please look upto the job which you are executing once.